# In which tables changes are made in openERP when an items is sold at Point of sale

Tags: python, odoo

I got one  table in which modifications are made :-account_bank_statement, what other tables are needed for the point of sale and if i make a sale in which tables modifications are made.I want to make a sale but not through the pos provided.

Comment: I've also got the stock_move and stock picking tables which are changed.There are other tables which are changed or these are the only ones?

Answer (score 0):

All the sales done through post is registered in post.order. If you are creating orders from an external source other than pos, you can create the order in this table and call the confirm bottom action. Rest changes in all other table will be done automatically..